# Apply changed code style to existing code in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I just changed the right margin for my project in Intellij. Can I apply it to all the files in my project currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke the Reformat Code action (Ctrl+Alt+L by default, I think) from the Project view. This will cause all files under the currently selected item to be reformatted. So you just need to do this when the root project node is selected, in order to achieve what you want.